# is there a simpler way of refreshing a NVD3 chart without reloading the entire page

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, nvd3.js

Hey I'm currently working on a DJANGO project that needs a real time NVD3 graph/chart displayed. I can get the page to auto refresh after a set period of time which refreshes the graph with the most up-to date data.

But I've been asked to try and get it to refresh the chart without refreshing the entire page

any help is appreciated

Comment: Are you using Django as an API backend? You could just use Ajax to grab new data and re-render the graph/chart.

Comment: yes i am using django as the api, but i cant really see that many examples online on how to implement ajax for the nvd3 charts and they aren't very clear is there any other way that can be recommended?

Comment: Using a long polling technique or web sockets should help you here. http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/60-simple-long-polling-example-with-javascript-and-jquery